# Android Animation XML example files?

Tags: android

*Hiya!*

I was wondering if anyone knows of some good Android Animation XML examples so that I could take a look at how they work?

Please and Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few in the Android API Demos that ship with the Android SDK (you can see them [online](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html), but they're a lot easier to browse locally). For even more examples, poke around the Android system [source code](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) to see animations Android system apps use.